# Erratic completion times when reading image sizes of online assets (using Python and requests)

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

I'm experimenting with reading image sizes over the internet (using Python 2.7 and `requests`).

Test image url 1: `https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/ax1WByM_460s.jpg`

Test image url 2: `https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/abMego9_460s.jpg`

The code is quite minimal:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

def get_web_img_dimensions(url):
    """
    Returns image dimensions
    """
    req = requests.get(url, headers={"Range": "bytes=0-1023",'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'})
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(req.content))
    print im.size
```

Running this on the provided **test image url 1** took `127` seconds. I next tried **text image url 2**. My code returned the correct answer in `0.5` seconds this time. Both images load almost instantaneously on my browser, which made me think reading 1024 bytes shouldn't be a big deal.

After a while, I tried **test image url 1** again. This time, it merely took `0.5` seconds to return image dimensions. But around the same time, trying **test image url 2** took `128` seconds. Strange role reversal!

What's going on under the hood here? These fluctuating time discrepancies don't seem to be correlated to image sizes at all. Secondly, how do I short circuit this code - such that if it's taking longer than x seconds, it breaks and returns `None`? By the way note that results using `urllib` or `urllib2` are similarly erratic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming per se, but how a library (python's request) and/or network requests work.

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano: I ask about short circuiting it as well, which is explicitly programming related. And the former half can be interpreted as a programming question in case my approach is found to be invalid and an alternative is suggested by an expert. Any way, you're entitled to your opinion.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Did you see this behavior also using python3? Regarding the second question at the end: look for timeout function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was indeed enabling a `timeout` for the call.

Caution: the `timeout` kicks in if the target remains uncommunicative for the length of the `timeout`. It's *not* a hard cap on when to abort the connection. Give a quick glance to **timeout** here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.request